# Migrate Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project to Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to migrate my [Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.project%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) classes to use [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), as the original has become obsolete. Previously, I was using the `ResetBuildStatus` method, which I cannot find the equivalent for in the new class.

I've managed to convert most of what there was, but this one is still evading me.

Old code:

```
Private _engine As New Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine
_engine.DefaultToolsVersion = "4.0"
_engine.RegisterLogger(BuildLogger)

Private _buildProject As New Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project(BuildEngine)
If _globalProperties IsNot Nothing Then
     For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In _globalProperties
         _buildProject.GlobalProperties.SetProperty(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
     Next kvp
End If
_buildProject.Load(_buildProfile)
```

New code:

```
Private _engine As New Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection
_engine.DefaultToolsVersion = "4.0"
_engine.RegisterLogger(BuildLogger)

Private _buildProject As New Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(_buildProfile, _globalProperties, "4.0", BuildEngine)
_buildProject.ResetBuildStatus() 'This does not exist
```